# Error loading cartopy: error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, gcc, pip, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

I am trying to load cartopy onto my system using `pip install cartopy`

The version of Python environment I am using is 3.5.3, which I am unable to change. I'm getting the following error:

`error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`

It also gives me this error:

```
Command "/opt/apps/python/3.5.3/bin/python3.5 -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build- 
eprit6ql/cartopy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open) 
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-4mg12j4p-record/install- 
record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" 
failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-eprit6ql/cartopy/
```

(Sorry it's a little messy)

If there's another way to install using pip or a similar alternative (like basemap for example) that could be recommended that would be helpful too!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

[Installation instructions](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/installing.html#installing) recommend to use `conda`. If you want to install from sources (using `pip`) you have to install a number of [requirements](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/installing.html#requirements).

PS. And to help us to help you you'd better show us the full error message. `'gcc' failed` is not enough to understand what's going on.